# Is it possible to create a cache directory that refuses unlink/delete?

Tags: filesystems, cache, fuse

I have a cache directory that stores files that should never change once downloaded. However, the program that uses this cache directory deletes the files from the cache. Is there any mechanism (like a fuse/bind option) that will allow me to create a rw directory that refuses `unlink`?

Comment: On what OS and what filesystem (if not using fuse)?

Comment: @A.B I'm using ext4, but I'm really open in any hack because if I can create a directory that doesn't permit unlink, but that I can have podman bindmount into my containers, I'll save a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

There's already such feature implemented in Linux for some filesystems: the *append mode* attribute. This attribute can only be changed by the *root* user (or an adequate capability). From [`chattr`](https://manpages.debian.org/e2fsprogs/chattr.1#ATTRIBUTES):

> ATTRIBUTES
>
> **A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be open in *append mode* for
> writing.** Only the superuser or a process possessing the
> CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Actually even if it's not described explicitly, this affect directories too: one can add (or link) files in them but can't remove or rename them anymore.

Attributes are supported at least on *ext4*, *xfs* and *btrfs* (but for example not on *tmpfs*) filesystems.

Full example. Normal behaviour:

```
$ mkdir mytest
$ echo 1 > mytest/foo
$ mv mytest/foo mytest/bar
$ echo 2 > mytest/foo
$ rm mytest/foo
```

Now with the attribute set:

```
$ sudo chattr +a mytest
$ echo 3 > mytest/foo
$ rm mytest/foo
rm: cannot remove 'mytest/foo': Operation not permitted
$ rm mytest/bar
rm: cannot remove 'mytest/bar': Operation not permitted
$ mv mytest/foo mytest/baz
mv: cannot move 'mytest/foo' to 'mytest/baz': Operation not permitted
```

This doesn't affect the files themselves, since they didn't receive the *append mode* attribute themselves:

```
$ echo 4 >> mytest/foo
$ echo 5 >> mytest/bar
$ cat mytest/foo
3
4
$ cat mytest/bar
1
5
```

They can still be truncated:

```
$ : > mytest/foo
$ cat mytest/foo
$
```

Or linked/unlinked elsewhere:

```
$ mkdir mytest2
$ ln mytest/foo mytest2/foo
$ rm mytest2/foo
$
```

The only way to remove the restriction which even applies to *root*, is for *root* to remove the *append only* attribute with `chattr -a mytest`.

Comment: This is amazing. Good thing they didn't documented it, or I wouldn't have asked the question. Thanks! I'll mark it as chosen when I confirm this works.